# what additional conditions on $\varphi$ (if any) are sufficient to ensure that if $G$ is abelian, then so is $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

If $\varphi :G \to H$ is an isomorphism, prove that $G$ is abelian if and only if $H$ is abelian. If
$\varphi :G \to H$ is a homomorphism, what additional conditions on $\varphi$ (if any) are sufficient to
ensure that if $G$ is abelian, then so is $H$?

**My   attempt** :It is given that $G$ is abelian and  $\varphi$ is a isomorphism,then for every element $h \in H$, there exists $g \in G $ such that $ h = \varphi(g)$. Then consider any two elements $h_1, h_2 \in H$ and let
$g_1, g_2 \in G$ be such that $h_1 = \varphi(g_1)$ and $h_2 = \varphi(g_2)$. We have $h_1h_2 = \varphi(g_1)\varphi(g_2) =\varphi(g_1g_2) = \varphi(g_2g_1) = \varphi(g_2)\varphi(g_1) = h_2h_1$. So $H$
is abelian

**My doubt**:If $\varphi :G \to H$ is a homomorphism,what additional conditions on $\varphi$ (if any) are sufficient to ensure that if $G$ is abelian, then so is $H$?

Comment: Well, in your proof, do you need $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be the *unique* elements that map to $h_1$ and $h_2$, or is it sufficient for them to be *some* elements that map to $h_1$ and to $h_2$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $ \varphi$ is one one   so i     mean $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be the unique map to $h_1$ and $h_2$

Comment: I know; but the question is, do you **need** them to be unique for your argument to work, or is it enough to know there is *at least one* $g_1$ that maps to $h_1$, etc?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i mean there is atleast one $g_1$ that map to $h_1$

Comment: Right; so that tells you, as Mark notes in his answer, one condition that guarantees the image is abelian which is weaker than "isomorphism".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the proof you only used the fact that $\varphi$ is surjective. So this is sufficient.

In general, if $\varphi$ is any homomorphism and $G$ is abelian then it follows that the image $\varphi(G)$ is abelian as well. But if the image is not all $H$ (i.e if $\varphi$ is not surjective) then $H$ itself might not be abelian.