# Will $B$ form an abelian group? Yes/No

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Is the following statement is true/false ?
>
> Given $A$ is an abelian  group and  $B$ is any group, suppose  $f: A \to B $ is homomorphism and  $f$ is not onto; then  $B$ is a abelian group

**My attempt** : I think  true . Take element  $a_1, a_2 \in  A$ and it is given that $A$ is abelian so $a_1a_2=a_2a_1$

since $f$ is homomorphism  then it implies  $ f(a_1 a_2)=f(a_1)f(a_2) = f(a_2)f(a_1)= f(a_2a_1)$

so $f(a_1)f(a_2) = f(a_2)f(a_1)$ where $f(a_1) , f(a_2) \in B $

This implies $B$ is abelian group

Comment: What about the case where $f$ maps all of $A$ to the identity of $B$? Your hypotheses do not seem to exclude this. On the other hand if $f$ **is** onto, then your conclusion is right.

Comment: You'll have to start with any two elements $b_1,b_2\in B$ and show that $b_1b_2=b_2b_1$.

Comment: Why exactly "$f(a_1)f(a_2) = f(a_2)f(a_1)$ for all $a_1,a_2 \in A$" implies that $B$ is abelian?

Comment: @Lubin  $f(1_A) = 1_B$  i think it will form  trivial homomorphism

Comment: take $f(a_1)=b_1$ and$ f(a_1) =b_2$ @azif00

Comment: The claim would imply that any group which had an abelian subgroup must be abelian.  This is clearly false. (it would certainly imply that all groups were abelian).

Comment: @jasmine What if $b_1,b_2 \in B$ cannot be written as $b_1=f(a_1)$ and $b_2 = f(a_2)$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in A$?

Comment: @azif00 im not able to  find out it...can u  explain its?

Comment: How does the answer you got here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922672/what-additional-conditions-on-varphi-if-any-are-sufficient-to-ensure-that-i not also answer this question?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft my question is little bit different from that previous post. it was about surjective  condition  but here i have put the condition on my question that $f$ is not surjective

Comment: And the answer given explicitly tells you what happens then.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft   im sorry for that.....actually I  didn't  fully  understand the previous post answer  so  i  re post again

Comment: There are so many ways to see that the claim is false. Lubin has explained where your argument goes wrong. The only thing you can say in the situation where $f : A \to B$ is a homomorphism with $A$ abelian is that $\operatorname{Im} f$ is abelian.

Comment: If you want to ask for clarification of an answer, please do that, or at least mention the original question so people don't have to start over in the explanations. As it stands, I cannot see how this question makes sense given that you were in a previous,answer told that the claim is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly false: take $B$ to be any non-abelian group and $A$ to be any abelian group. Then there is a map $f: A \to B$ sending all elements of $A$ to the identity element of $B$, which is clearly a non-surjective homomorphism.